# Transfer Bitcoin from between two different wallets

Tags: blockchain, wallet, ethereum

In my application i want to received payment from different user. Each user may use different wallets like mycelium, jaxx and many more... My application's wallet is in coinbase, is it possible to transfer coin from mycelium, jaxx to coinbase ?

Just by sharing the receiver wallet address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for that question and all legitimate wallets work in transfer of bitcoins just by sharing your wallet address,it doesnt matter what kind of wallet your using,what matters is having bitcoins.

Comment: Thanks you for your prompt response. Suppose user X (from Jaxx) has transferred 1 bitcoin to our application's wallet's in coinbase. Is there a way to cross verify like X amount is came from this wallet ?

Comment: Nope, you cannot know which wallet was used to send the BTC.

Comment: Can we achieve this by writing contact in blockchain (BTC) or solidity (ETH) ?